# Multiplying variables identified by vectors in R

Tags: r, apply

I need to manually create interaction terms for 6*3 variables. I have stored the names of these variables into two vectors, let us call them a and b. Let us call my dataframe df.

```
a <- c("var1","var2","var3")
b <- c("varA","varB","varC","varD","varE","varF")
```

I could manually create 18 different variables, as in:

```
df$var1.A <- df$var1*df$varA
df$var1.B <- df$var1*df$varB
df$var2.A <- df$var2*df$varA  
df$var2.B <- df$var2*df$varB
```

And so on and so forth, but this would obviously be inelegant and error-prone. I have tried to play around with apply, sapply and the like, but have not found the solution yet.

**Update**

Thanks to @akrun who set me on the right path with his answer. However, I now need to do compute another set of interactions, this time using 'transform', so the basic syntax would be

```
df <- transform(df, var1.A = var1*varA)
df <- transform(df, var2.A = var2*varA)
df <- transform(df, var1.B = var1*varB)
df <- transform(df, var2.B = var1*varB)
```

And so on and so forth for the other 17 interactions. I tried to adapt the code @akrun provided to this task but have not managed to.

The reason why I need to calculate these interaction terms is that I am using Amelia to multiply impute missing data. Since interactions are going to be in my analysis, I need to include them when estimating missing values, and Amelia does not do that automatically for me. So I computed the 18 interaction terms and had Amelia generate some imputed dataset. However, the imputed interaction terms are not necessarily consistent with their constituent terms, which also had missing data that Amelia imputed. Therefore, in order to run my analysis, I need to compute new interaction terms based on the complete values and the imputed values. Amelia's developers suggest to do that via 'transform', which, if applied on the whole Amelia object, works across all the imputations. I have not been able to achieve the same with the format 'df$var1.A <- df$var1*df$varA', which was the initial subject of my question, hence the update.

**End update**

Can anyone help?

Any solution that simultaneously assigns the right values to the right place in the function and creates a name that collapses the names of the multiplied variables separated by "." would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: this? `mapply(function(x,y){paste(x,y,sep = "*")},a,b)`

Comment: whats your exact desired outcome?

Answer (score 3):

We can do this all at one by doing `expand.grid` on the `vector`s

```
ab <- expand.grid(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create the new column names based on the expanded combination of vectors

```
nm1 <- sub("\\.var", ".", do.call(paste, c(ab, sep=".")))
```

and then loop through each row, subset the columns, multiply and assign the output to create the new columns

```
df[nm1] <- apply(ab , 1, FUN = function(x) Reduce(`*`, df[x]))
df
#var1 var2 var3 varA varB varC varD varE varF var1.A var2.A var3.A var1.B var2.B var3.B var1.C var2.C var3.C var1.D var2.D var3.D var1.E var2.E var3.E var1.F
#1    3    9    6    9    1    7    3    2    5     27     81     54      3      9      6     21     63     42      9     27     18      6     18     12     15
#2    3    3    4    2    5    1    3    7    4      6      6      8     15     15     20      3      3      4      9      9     12     21     21     28     12
#3    7    7    7    1    7    6    4    6    3      7      7      7     49     49     49     42     42     42     28     28     28     42     42     42     21
#4    5    8    7    5    2    6    2    7    2     25     40     35     10     16     14     30     48     42     10     16     14     35     56     49     10
#5    6    3    3    2    3    1    9    9    1     12      6      6     18      9      9      6      3      3     54     27     27     54     27     27      6
#  var2.F var3.F
#1     45     30
#2     12     16
#3     21     21
#4     16     14
#5      3      3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 5 * 9, replace = TRUE), 
         5, 9, dimnames = list(NULL, c(a, b))))
```

Comment: Works fine! Yet I still dont get what the OP wants.

Comment: @AndreElrico  Thanks, based on the OP's description, wants to create 18 columns and in my expanded 'ab', it is 18 columns `length(nm1)
#[1] 18`

Comment: @akrun Thanks a million! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @akrun Sorry if I bother you again, but I need to perform a related but different set of transformations. I need to use "transform", so the basic syntax based on the data you kindly provided would be: 'df <- transform(df, var1.A = var1*varA)' and so on and so forth for the other 17 interactions. I tried to adapt the code you provided to this task but have not managed to. Would you be so kind to help out again?

Comment: I have now updated my original question so it reflects this additional request. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If `y` is your response variable then run your linear model like this:

```
lm(y ~ (var1 + var2 + var3) * (varA + varB + varC + varD + varE + varF), df)
```

That will give an intercept, main effects and interactions between the first set and second set but not within each set (which is my understanding of what you want).

If the idea is to use `a` and `b` then:

```
fo <- sprintf("y ~ (%s) * (%s)", paste(a, collapse = "+"), paste(b, collapse = "+"))
lm(fo, df)
```

For example, using the builtin anscombe data.frame:

```
lm(y1 ~ (y2 + y3) * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), anscombe)
```

gives:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ (y2 + y3) * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), data = anscombe)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           y2           y3           x1           x2           x3  
   259.9304       8.6943     -47.1185     -25.9360           NA           NA  
         x4        y2:x1        y2:x2        y2:x3        y2:x4        y3:x1  
    -0.2124       0.1627           NA           NA           NA       3.5765  
      y3:x2        y3:x3        y3:x4  
         NA           NA           NA
```

Comment: I don't want to post it as an answer, as it is based on the dataset that is created in the background of your model, but if they really need the data they can use: `data.frame(model.matrix(~ (var1 + var2 + var3) * (varA + varB + varC + varD + varE + varF) , df))` and ignore the intercept column. And a more general approach: `data.frame(model.matrix(as.formula(sprintf("~ (%s) * (%s)", paste(a, collapse = "+"), paste(b, collapse = "+"))), df))`

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck! Not quite what I needed, but I was not aware of this syntax and it may be very helpful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Easy as

```
setNames(merge(a, b), c("col1", "col2"))
```